# How to add language pack to the android os , version 2.3.3

Tags: android

I am having android os , version 2.3.3 in my sony ericsson xperia  mobile phone. I cant read a sms , which is in my "regional" language using my phone.

But I heard, in some later version , we can read sms which wrote in some kind of regional languages also. So, please tell me how to add the regional language pack to the android os version 2.3.3.

Note :If i receive a sms in tamil language , then the phone should detect the language automatically and show that sms in tamil.